# looping througn mysql result in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this piece of code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
    $product["user_name"] = $row["user_name"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

and it gave me this result

```
{"products":[{"user_id":"2","user_name":"BOZ2"},{"user_id":"25","user_name":"POZ"},{"user_id":"28","user_name":"a"}],"success":1}
```

and now i am using ...

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {

    $sql = "select  statement";

     $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    // fetch the results into an array
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
     $response["products"] = array();
     $product["user_name"] = $row["user_name"];
     $product["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
    // convert to json
    $json = array_push($response["products"], $product);
    // echo the json string
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);
```

and it is giving me this..looping same result

```
{"products":[{"user_name":"BOZ2","user_id":"2"}],"success":1}{"products":[{"user_name":"BOZ2","user_id":"2"}],"success":0,"message":"success"}
```

how can i make it loop through all the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetchAll returns all rows in an array. All you need is just this

```
$sql = "select  statement";
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
$response = array();
$response["products"] = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```